# How to create a template for visual studio 2008 for multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio

I want to create a template kind of thing where there will be more than one project in the solution. Like one test project + one normal project + some other project.

How to do that.

When I export a template it exports only one project.

Answer (score 0):

We had to resort to a powershell script to do this, as we couldn't find a reliable way of doing this.

Comment: can you please explain in a bit detail. I am also interested.

Answer (score 0):

This is fully supported but you'll need to modify the .vstemplate file manually.  Starting by running the Save as Template on each project is a good first step.  Now you need to bind them together in another .vstemplate.  More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24